# The same CSS files are being downloaded twice inside my asp.net MVC web application

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and I used an online web template name “Charizma”. But when I use the IE developer tool and I capture the network I have noted that some CSS files are being downloaded twice or more. And the initiator of the file  download differ, and it is  either `XMLHttpRequest` or `<link rel=,…….>`. so is it normal to have this behaviour ? Part of the network data is as follow:-

[image]

Comment: What is in the response and request headers of those three requests (and please add that as text)

Comment: the response code is 200  and the type is text/css

Comment: You can click to the details view somewhere. That will show you the headers

Comment: @johnG, have you tried this in different browsers?  It might just be an IE-specific bug, though I doubt it.

Comment: Set [expiry headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for your static content, then the browser will only download them once no matter how many times they're requested.

Comment: As these are being loaded on or around either the DOM content loaded or window onload event (it's not easy from the screenshot which the line represents, although probably the former) I *suspect* the library lazy-loads dependencies for each module to make sure that they are available - relying on the cache to avoid duplicate downloads. Check your static content response headers to make sure you're sending a far-future expiration time.